# Stopping Spark structured streaming app after the write commit and before the read commit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

What is the expected behavior if the streaming is stopped after the write commit and before the read commit? Should I expect data duplication?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your source and sink? the data re-play is based on your check-point location, spark usually updated the check-point location when the task is completely processed. so if there are any exception before the sink is processed, then the check-point is not updated, that means the data will be replayed by the source.

Comment: refer this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics